# splunk regex with condition

Tags: java, regex, splunk

I have splunk query using which i want to filter out the log which has time greater than 100 or any number.

```
2015-09-04 14:31:55.015 INFO : [org.perf4j.TimingLogger:426] - start[1441402314909] time[103] tag[getDetails]
2015-09-04 14:31:56.437 INFO : [org.perf4j.TimingLogger:426] - start[1441402316435] time[12] tag[getDetails]
2015-09-04 14:31:57.654 INFO : [org.perf4j.TimingLogger:426] - start[1441402317653] time[20] tag[getDetails]
2015-09-04 14:31:58.721 INFO : [org.perf4j.TimingLogger:426] - start[1441402318720] time[10] tag[getDetails]
```

Here is my spunk regex. This could filter outs above 4 line from my log but I'm unable to put the condition further (greater than ). Tried eval but couldn't get the intended result.

```
sourcetype="abc" *|regex _raw=time\[(\d+)\]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value you want to filter out is greater than or equal to 100 then check for 3 digits:

```
sourcetype="abc" *|regex _raw=time\[(\d{3})\]
```

This way only values of 100 or higher will match.

**EDIT**: If you're looking for a number above a range (eg. `60`):

```
sourcetype="abc" *|regex _raw=time\[([6-9]\d|\d{3,})\]
```

For a specific number and above (eg. `33+`):

```
sourcetype="abc" *|regex _raw=time\[(33|[3-9][3-9]|[4-9]\d+|[1-9][0-9]\d+)\]
```

To disallow numbers with leading zeros:

```
sourcetype="abc" *|regex _raw=time\[(33|[3-9][3-9]|[4-9]\d+|[1-9][0-9]\d+|[1-9]\d{2,})\]
```

Comment: I just took 100 as example. I want this to be any number.

Comment: Please use real examples, not one's that aren't relevant to your question.

Comment: This is real example as i had mentioned in my question that it should be 100 (any number). Not sure why you think it's not real example.